# How should metrics be added to a multi-headed TensorFlow estimator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, metrics

I previously created metrics for a TensorFlow Classifier referencing `predictions['logits']` to calculate the metrics. I have changed the model from a Classifier to an Estimator in order to enable multi-objective learning (using MultiHead). However, this has caused Python to throw an error since now the elements of `predictions` are keyed by pairs of the head name and original key, e.g. ('label1','logits') for a head with name 'label1'.

I'd like to allow for dynamic generation of metrics based on a configuration file in order to more easily train and test a variety of models with different label combinations. The problem now is that the `metric_fn` parameter to `tf.estimator.add_metrics` does not take any additional parameters to allow for dynamically determined or constructed metrics.

How can I generate an estimator with multiple heads and custom metrics for each head?

Answer (score 1):

Build a class around the model creation that holds the model configuration and use a member function for the `metric_fn` parameter.

`class ModelBuilder:
  # constructor storing configuration options in self
  def __init__(self, labels, other_config_args):
    self.labels = labels
    ...
  # Function for building the estimator with multiple heads (multi-objective)
  def build_estimator(self, func_args):
    heads = []
    for label in self.labels:
      heads.append(tf.estimator.MultiClassHead(n_classes=self.nclasses[label], name=label))
    head = tf.estimator.MultiHead(heads)
    estimator = tf.estimator.DNNEstimator(head=heads,...) # or whatever type of estimator you want
    estimator = tf.estimator.add_metrics(estimator, self.model_metrics)
    return estimator
  # Member function that adds metrics to the estimator based on the model configuration params
  def model_metrics(self, labels, predictions, features):
    metrics = {}
    for label in self.labels: # generate a metric for each head name
      metrics['metric_name'] = metric_func(features,labels,predictions[(label,'logits')])
    return metrics`